# Scan of fiegn client present in other package jar

Tags: spring-boot, feign

We have one custom jar which has fiegn client in com.pack.mav.tru.client package of jar.

Now this jar is imported using pom.xml in our spring boot application.

In this main application we added the component scan with base packes and also that jar package.

Yet we see null object, when we autowire that fiegn client in that jar one class.

What we are missing, please help.

```
package com.pack.mav.tru.client;
@FeignClient(name = "user")
public interface UserClient {

  public void getUser(@PathVariable String id);
}

package com.pack.mav.tru.service;
public class ProductService {

@Autowired
userClient userclient;

public void method(string id) {
  userClient.getuser(id);  ---> Here userClient is null
}
```

The above classes are present in one jar

We import same jar in our main spring application and added scan in main application class as below.

```
@ComponentScan(basePackages = { "com.mav.pack.*", "com.pack.mav.tru.client.*"})
```

Comment: Do you have the correct dependencies? And the name is "feign" not "fiegn". Please show some code/dependency/pom to evaluate.

Comment: yeah its feign client

Comment: @TomStroemer updated with code, please check